# SQL - Two DISTINCTs performing very poorly

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

I've got two tables containing a column with the same name. I try to find out which distinct values exist in Table2 but don't exist in Table1. For that I have two SELECTs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Table1

SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Table2
```

Both SELECTs finish within 2 Seconds and return about 10 rows each. If I restructure my query to find out which values are missing in Table1, the query takes several minutes to finish:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Table1
WHERE Field NOT IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Field
        FROM Table2
    )
```

My temporary workaround is inserting the results of the second distinct in a temporary table an comparing against it. But the performance still isn't great.

Does anyone know why this happens? I guess because SQL-Server keeps recalculating the second DISTINCT but why would it? Shouldn't SQL-Server optimize this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will improve performance but i'd use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql):

```
SELECT Field
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT Field
FROM Table2
```

There is no need to use `DISTINCT`  because `EXCEPT` is a set operator that removes duplicates.

> EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t
>   output by the right input query.

- The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
- The data types must be compatible.

Comment: I used EXCEPT and it sped up my query a lot! Thank you!